# How to hook up a third party library to Angular 4 for use as a service

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add [collect.js](https://github.com/ecrmnn/collect.js) to my Angular 4 application built using the Angular CLI, which has it's own typings file, but I don't understand how to import the package, and start using it.  The import below appears to get me the exports of the package, but I don't understand how to access them:

```
import * as Collection from 'collect.js';
```

This is the `collect.js` file being imported:

```
function Collection(collection) {
  this.items = collection || [];
}

Collection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = require('./methods/symbol.iterator');

Collection.prototype.all = require('./methods/all');
// ... removed for brevity
Collection.prototype.zip = require('./methods/zip');

module.exports = collection => new Collection(collection);
module.exports.default = collection => new Collection(collection);
```

The import Collection is a method as you'd expect from the module export, but I can't invoke it without VSCode saying it has no call signature, and I'm also not sure if the typings are automatically loaded or if I need to manually add them.  I was hoping to make a service out of it by importing it once then just mapping methods, and then providing that in the CoreModule so I can DI and use it wherever I want in the application, but I'm not sure how to access the API in order to make it a service.

Comment: Any chance you are using the angular cli?

Comment: Hi @R.Richards yah I'm using the CLI

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards I used that link and got the typings setup properly, and then calling Collection.default().methodName() shows the typings for the methods :)  If you post an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to add a 3rd party library to you Angular application, and you are using the Angular CLI, then follow the instruction at the link below.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

A summary of the steps are as follows

Install the library, and library typings, using `npm`.

```
npm install <library-name> --save
npm install @types/<library-name> --save-dev
```

Then add the library to the types array `src/tsconfig.app.json`

```
"types":[
  "<library-name>"
]
```

Use the library in code as normal.

Refer to the link above if you have any issues.